# Voronoi diagram of two data sets

Tags: plotting, graphics, mesh, computational-geometry

My primary data is

```
data = {{257.3`, 493.7`}, {43.666666666666664`,490.5`}, {111.91176470588235`,461.20588235294116`},{345.2142857142857`,460.5`}, {420.88461538461536`, 436.34615384615387`}, {318.1`,408.46`}, {277.`,400.7`}, {273.5`, 383.`}, {444.`,381.5`}, {208.28571428571428`,379.7857142857143`}, {510.9166666666667`,367.66666666666663`}, {584.7`, 366.`}, {301.125`, 355.5`}, {116.875`, 352.75`}, {423.14285714285717`,340.2142857142857`}, {360.2142857142857`,340.07142857142856`}, {234.7`, 318.1`}, {287.25`,303.25`}, {474.65`, 301.35`}, {110.71428571428571`, 299.5`}, {440.95714285714286`, 297.3`}, {536.4545454545455`,277.72727272727275`}, {321.`, 268.2142857142857`}, {439.3125`,249.875`}, {306.42857142857144`,242.78571428571428`}, {505.42857142857144`,242.10714285714286`}, {603.5370370370371`,217.3888888888889`}, {618.0909090909091`, 212.86363636363637`}, {248.5`, 212.875`}, {110.07894736842105`, 199.60526315789474`}, {384.7857142857143`, 188.`}, {572.8333333333334`,148.66666666666669`}, {33.`, 133.`}, {447.31481481481484`, 129.24074074074076`}, {206.33333333333334`, 116.41666666666669`}, {399.1764705882353`, 98.35294117647061`}, {33.3`,60.366666666666674`}, {216.875`, 44.`}, {328.77272727272725`, 40.31818181818181`}, {435.5`,38.5`}, {58.88461538461539`,37.11538461538464`}, {464.44117647058823`,23.323529411764696`}, {534.`, 1.375`}}
```

To plot Voronoi diagram of this set of data we have:

```
vm = VoronoiMesh[data];
interiorfaces = MeshPrimitives[vm, {2, "Interior"}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], {Yellow, interiorfaces}}]
```

which results in:

[image]

Now, I want to break my primary data to two sets, and to have different colors for each set in Voronoi diagram.

```
data1 = {{257.3`, 493.7`}, {43.666666666666664`, 490.5`}, {111.91176470588235`, 461.20588235294116`}, {345.2142857142857`, 460.5`}, {420.88461538461536`, 436.34615384615387`}, {318.1`, 408.46`}, {277.`, 400.7`}, {273.5`, 383.`}, {444.`, 381.5`}, {208.28571428571428`, 379.7857142857143`}, {510.9166666666667`, 367.66666666666663`}, {584.7`, 366.`}, {301.125`, 355.5`}, {116.875`, 352.75`}, {423.14285714285717`,340.2142857142857`}, {360.2142857142857`, 340.07142857142856`}, {234.7`, 318.1`}, {287.25`,303.25`}, {474.65`, 301.35`}, {110.71428571428571`,299.5`}, {440.95714285714286`, 297.3`}, {536.4545454545455`,277.72727272727275`}, {321.`, 268.2142857142857`}, {439.3125`,249.875`}, {306.42857142857144`,242.78571428571428`}, {505.42857142857144`, 242.10714285714286`}};

vm1 = VoronoiMesh[data1];
interiorfaces1 = MeshPrimitives[vm1, {2, "Interior"}];

data2 = {{603.5370370370371`,217.3888888888889`}, {618.0909090909091`, 212.86363636363637`}, {248.5`, 212.875`}, {110.07894736842105`,199.60526315789474`}, {384.7857142857143`, 188.`}, {572.8333333333334`, 148.66666666666669`}, {33.`,133.`}, {447.31481481481484`, 129.24074074074076`}, {206.33333333333334`,116.41666666666669`}, {399.1764705882353`, 98.35294117647061`}, {33.3`, 60.366666666666674`}, {216.875`,44.`}, {328.77272727272725`, 40.31818181818181`}, {435.5`,38.5`}, {58.88461538461539`, 37.11538461538464`}, {464.44117647058823`, 23.323529411764696`}, {534.`, 1.375`}};

vm2 = VoronoiMesh[data2];
interiorfaces2 = MeshPrimitives[vm2, {2, "Interior"}];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], {{Brown, interiorfaces1}, {Blue, interiorfaces2}}}]
```

which results in

[image]

Besides the fact that some parts are missing, it also seems that even if the missing parts, in some way, to be added, one cannot get the original Voronoi plot. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[nearestInteriorFaceIndices, nearestInteriorFaces]

nearestInteriorFaceIndices[mr_, pts_] := 
  Intersection[MeshCellIndex[mr, {2, "Interior"}], 
   Join @@ (NearestMeshCells[mr, #] & /@ pts)];

nearestInteriorFaces[mr_, pts_] := 
  MeshPrimitives[mr, nearestInteriorFaceIndices[mr, pts]];

HighlightMesh[vm, {Style[nearestInteriorFaceIndices[vm, data1], Red], 
  Style[nearestInteriorFaceIndices[vm, data2], Green]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], 
  Red, nearestInteriorFaces[vm, data1], 
  Green, nearestInteriorFaces[vm, data2]}]
```

[image]

**Note:** In versions older than version 12.1, you can use

```
ClearAll[nearestInteriorFaceIndices]

nearestInteriorFaceIndices[mr_, pts_] := 
   Intersection[MeshCellIndex[mr, {2, "Interior"}],
      Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex[mr, pts]];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data1 = RandomReal[{-10, 0}, {100, 2}];
data2 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100, 2}];
data = Join[data1, data2];
n = Length[data];
k = Length[data1];
vm = VoronoiMesh[data];
Polys = MeshPrimitives[vm, 2];
inPolys = MeshPrimitives[vm, {2, "Interior"}];
outPolys = Complement[Polys, inPolys];
rerangePolys = 
  Polys . (RegionMember[#, data] & /@ Polys /. {False -> 0, 
      True -> 1});
Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], {Purple, 
   Complement[Table[rerangePolys[[i]], {i, 1, k}], outPolys]}, {Brown,
    Complement[Table[rerangePolys[[i]], {i, k + 1, n}], 
    outPolys]}, {LightGreen, outPolys}}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace `/. {False -> 0, True -> 1}` with `//Boole`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
findCorrespondingPolygon[pt_] := Select[
  interiorfaces,
  RegionMember[#, pt] &
  ]

region1 = Cases[
   findCorrespondingPolygon /@ data1,
   _Polygon,
   {2}
   ];

region2 = Cases[
   findCorrespondingPolygon /@ data2,
   _Polygon,
   {2}
   ];

Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[White],
  {{Brown, region1}, {Blue, region2}}
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]